# How to return strongly type List F#

Tags: linq, f#

### i need to return list from database as strongly type

```
    type private EntityConnection =SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionString="Server=.;Initial Catalog=db;user id=sa;password=pass;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",Pluralize = true>



type CustomerName(firstName, middleInitial, lastName) = 
    member this.FirstName = firstName
    member this.MiddleInitial = middleInitial
    member this.LastName = lastName  


 let context=EntityConnection.GetDataContext()

        // GET /api/values
member x.Get() =
    query { for g in context.tblTest do
               select (new CustomerName(g.firstName, g.middleInitial, g.lastName))  
            }
    |> Seq.toList
```

Return error message

"Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: Your `CustomerName` class is not actually as strongly typed as you assume. Try this: `new CustomerName( 42, 3.1415, false )`. This will compile. Can you guess why? Use records instead of classes. Better language support, better performance, better overall.

Comment: Thanks it's first time work with F#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the fields from the `query` as a tuple, then use `Seq.map` to construct your `CustomerName` object.

```
member x.Get() =
    query { for g in context.tblTest do
            select (g.firstName, g.middleInitial, g.lastName)
          }
    |> Seq.map (fun (firstName,middleInitial,lastName) -> new CustomerName(firstName, middleInitial, lastName))
    |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Aaron
but i got an  Error "Unexpected infix operator in member definition "
here " |> Seq.map"